# Flutter - can't scroll to the bottom of listView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have code like this:

```dart
    Column(children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: IconButton(
              color: theme.iconTheme.color,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: allOperations,
              controller: listViewController,
            ),
          ),
    ]);
```

and I want to scroll to the bottom after widget is built.

```dart
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          listViewController.jumpTo(listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
```

but it doesn't work. Always remain about 150px to scroll down.

Anyone had this problem?

**UPDATE**
It remains number of pixels  to scroll down depending on number of element in `ListView`. For example if I have 20 elements there will remain about 50px to bottom if 30 then about 80px.

**Problem example** (let assume widget take all height of screen and if is higher than screen then it can be scrolled): 
full height of ListView: 2000px 
screen height: 600px 
maxScrollExtent should be 1400px but is 1300px.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to leave some white space below your list? This is typically a SizedBox and it would allow you to see the rest of your list and then leave some more depending on the size you choose.

Comment: I don't want white space below list. I can see rest elements but maxScrollExtent has wrong value. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

adding Timer before scroll may solve your problem, I guess listview needs some time to add a new item.

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  listViewController.jumpTo(listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent);
    });
});
```

you can also try "animateTo" instead:

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    listViewController.animateTo(
      listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: adding Padding as following may help:
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
      child: ....),

Comment: unfortunately not help

Comment: so, try to add a SizedBox with a dynamic height depending on the number of items in the list

Comment: The Timer approach worked for me after hours of searching online and watching youtube tutorials. I'm pulling data from firebase using FirestoreQueryBuilder pagination